# React JS TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: reactjs

I have tried changing {WrongLetters.length > 0 &

Wrong

}; to {WrongLetters ?.length > 0 &

Wrong

}; But still doesn't output the desired output. {WrongLetters.map() } also gives the same error

Should output : the paragraph Wrong and the letters but only outputs 0

```
 const WrongLetters = ({WrongLetters}) => {
return (
    <div className='wrong-letters-container'>
        <div id='wrong-letters'>
        {WrongLetters.length > 0 & <p>Wrong</p>};

        {WrongLetters.map((letter,i) =>{
            return(
                <span key={i}>{letter}</span>
            )})
            .reduce((prev, curr)=>prev === null ? [curr] : [prev,','.curr ],null)
        };
        </div>
      </div>
       );
       }
```

Comment: are you sure WrongLetters is actually iterable? Is it an array? Your should also use `&&`  instead of a single `&` to render the `<p>Wrong</p>`

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid having the

> Cannot read properties of undefined

you'll have to add the question mark after both your WrongLetters call. Also you need a double && for the conditional rendering.

```
{WrongLetters?.length > 0 && <p>Wrong</p>};

{WrongLetters?.map((letter,i) =>{
    return(
        <span key={i}>{letter}</span>
    )})
    .reduce((prev, curr)=>prev === null ? [curr] : [prev,','.curr ],null)    };
```

Comment: did that, doesn't output anything. I need to see the <p>Wrong</p> and the letters

Comment: maybe WrongLetters is really undefined ? Where do you get the value from ? did you console log it ? Check where you instantiate the component and if the value you pass through props is right.